# How to add a column to a dataset made up of an association of associations?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations, data-science

A dataset can be created in at least two ways: first, from a list of associations, second, from an association of associations (I know that it is also possible to create it as a list of list and an association of lists, but these last two cases are not relevant).

1.
This is a list of associations.

```
ds = Dataset@{
    <|"nombre" -> "Aileen Agüero García", "edad" -> 25,"licenciatura" -> "Economía", 
     "universidad" -> "PUCP"|>, 
    <|"nombre" -> "Alvaro Gálvez Pasco","edad" -> 45, "licenciatura" -> "Ciencia política", 
     "universidad" -> "PUCP"|>,
    <|"nombre" -> "Gastón Zapata ", "edad" -> 55,"licenciatura" -> "Antropología", 
    "universidad" -> "PUCP"|>,
    <|"nombre" -> "Jose Velasco", "edad" -> 55,"licenciatura" -> "Economía", "universidad"-> 
    "PUCP"|>
    };
```

and the dataset is:

[image: ds]

If I want to add a column I do the following:

```
(* Agregar una columna con distintos valores a un dataset *)
col1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}; (*se crea una lista de valores*)
nuevo = Dataset[AssociationThread["ID" -> #] & /@col1];
Join[nuevo, ds, 2] (*finalmente se unen los dos datasets usando el nivel 
de especificación 2*)
```

And the output is:

[image: ds2]

2.
Now, if I have an association of associations:

```
baseDeDatos = <|
  "Registro1" -> <|"Nombre" -> "Juan", "Edad" -> 25,"Ciudad" -> "Madrid"|>, 
  "Registro2" -> <|"Nombre" -> "Maria", "Edad" -> 30,"Ciudad" -> "Barcelona"|>, 
  "Registro3" -> <|"Nombre" -> "Pedro", "Edad" -> 22,"Ciudad" -> "Valencia"|>|>
```

[image: ds3]

I don't know how to add a column to it. For example, I have tried with the following code:

```
ds2[All, Append[{"Estado civil" -> "Soltero", 
   "Estado civil" -> "Casado", "Estado civil" -> "Viudo"}]]
```

But there is an error in the output. Please help me!

[image: ds4]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ds[All, 
   Module[{$c = 0}, <|"ID" -> ++$c, #|> &]]
```

[image]

```
ds2[All, 
 Module[{$c = 0}, 
   <|"ID" -> ++$c, #, 
     "Estado civil" -> {"Soltero", "Casado", "Viudo"}[[$c]]|> &]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can add items using Prepend/Append like e.g. to add an ID number:

```
c = 1;
ds = Prepend[#, ID -> c++] & /@ baseDeDatos
```

[image]

Note that MMA now displays the data set column wise, because we have one 4 items:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
base =
  <|"Registro1" -> <|"Nombre" -> "Juan", "Edad" -> 25, "Ciudad" -> "Madrid"|>, 
   "Registro2" -> <|"Nombre" -> "Maria", "Edad" -> 30, "Ciudad" -> "Barcelona"|>, 
   "Registro3" -> <|"Nombre" -> "Pedro", "Edad" -> 22, "Ciudad" -> "Valencia"|>|>;

nuevo =
  {"Estado civil" -> "Soltero", "Estado civil" -> "Casado", "Estado civil" -> "Viudo"};

AssociationThread[Keys @ base, 
  MapThread[Append, {Values @ base, nuevo}]] // Dataset
```

[image]